# Is it possible to define array as constant in with Symfony Framework?

Tags: symfony1, constants, symfony-1.4

Constants are defined in YAML format in the config/app.yaml file. However, when I try to define an array as

const_arr: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']

and use sfConfig::get('app_const_arr'), I don't getting anything back. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
app:
   my_array:
       values: [foo, bar]


sfConfig::get('app_my_array_values');
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Now why does it not work when 'values' is omitted I have no clue!

Comment: I don't know, it works for me only with two-level entities in yml.

Answer (score 2):

+1'd to Darmen's answer. If you wanted to stick with your original YAML, you can add a dummy layer in the YAML - precede it with a period (`.`). For example, in `apps/yourapp/config.yml`:

```
all:
  .dummy_layer_here:
    const_arr: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
```

which should allow you to do `sfConfig::get('app_const_arr')`.